# wxpython drawing to window causes message dialogs to crash

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

im making a little paint app using wxpython like this:

```
from wx import *

class Canvas(ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, ID_ANY,(0, 0), size=DefaultSize, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#666666')

        self.sizer = BoxSizer()
        self.EnableScrolling(True,True)
        self.window = Window(self, size=(200,200))
        self.window.SetBackgroundColour('#ffffff')
        self.sizer.Add(self.window)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetVirtualSize((1000,1000))
        self.SetScrollRate( 1, 1 )

        self.Bind(EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        dc = PaintDC(self.window)
        dc.BeginDrawing()
        dc.DrawLine( 0,0, 100, 100)
        dc.EndDrawing()

class Paint(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        Fraself.__init__( self, parent, title=title, size=(500,400), style=  CAPTION | RESIZE_BORDER | CLOSE_BOX)
        self.CreateStatusBar(2,style= STB_DEFAULT_STYLE & ~(STB_SIZEGRIP) )
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.Show(True)

        menu= Menu()
        test = menu.Append(ID_ANY, "Create","Shows a MessageDialog")
        self.Bind(EVT_MENU, self.Test, test)

        menubar = MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(menu,"Dialog")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    def Test(self, e):
        dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'This is a test dialog.', 'Hi', 
            wx.OK)
        dial.Show()

app = App(False)
frame = Paint(None, 'Paintbox')
app.MainLoop()
```

but there's some strange problem with MessageDialog where i can't show it because i'm using a PaintDC elsewhere in the program. If I comment out the line `self.Bind(EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)` i can get the dialogs to show, but if i'm painting as well the dialog will crash the program without printing any error output. i'm working with wxpython 3.0, python 2.7, and Windows 8.

some other kinds of dialog (Dialog, FileDialog) i can show without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your OnPaint, call:

```
e.Skip()
```

In your Test, call:

```
dial.ShowModal()
```

instead of dial.Show(), unless you really want to show a mode-less message dialog, which I bet you don't. You should also set a parent to your MessageDialog. It should be self (meaning Paint object) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the event handler to `self`, but it is painting `self.window`.  Paint events are picky about things like that.  You need to bind the handler to the window where the `wx.PaintDC` will be used for drawing.